# How to edit passwords saved in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I know we can go to chrome://settings/passwords#passwords to find the saved passwords, but is there a way to **edit** any of the saved passwords?

Every now and then we come across 2 types of challenges which end up saving the wrong passwords in Google Chrome:
1) The password gets encrypted while submitting and Chrome ends up saving the encrypted one
2) There are 2 password fields (eg: password and DOB) and Chrome ends up saving the wrong field

I guess the only solution for the aforementioned scenarios is to find a way to EDIT the saved versions of the passwords. Would appreciate any tips...

Comment: Never tried that but seems that it can be done. Chrome stores encrypted passwords in SqlLite database at `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases`. Windows API functions `CryptUnprotectData` and `CryptProtectData` can be used to decrypt or encrypt password (`on same machine by same user only`).

Answer (score 7):

For people that still want an easy solution for this, go to https://passwords.google.com/. There you can change all your stored passwords...

Comment: That works, except you cannot override an existing entry with a new password value. I get an error. The solution I've found is to manually delete all passwords I want to replace then import the .csv again.

Answer (score 6):

Type this into the address bar:

```
chrome://flags
```

Then you can set the import/export passwords to on which enables you to export the password lists, edit, and re-import them.

Probably a good idea to reset the flag to its previous state afterwards.

Comment: This answer appears to be incomplete (at best). (1) You say “… you can set the import/export passwords to on which enables you ….” What does that mean? (2) How does the user “export the password lists, edit, and re-import them”?

Comment: OK, without setting the flag as above, you can export your passwords, but there is no way to import them.

By setting the flag to 'enable', this gives the extra setting in the Chrome settings password section to import the file.

So you can now export the passwords list (as I did because my webmail provider changed the login server), change the info, save the file and import it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It actually works.

Comment: Thank you, but be careful as I expected it to replace the new login data, it made duplicate usernames with different passwords. So I had to go to clear browsing data and clear all my passwords and reimport them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible in Chrome, its [help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) doesn't list this option.

Also in this [forum topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/BzOWUz-nN8s/i1iULZMLAwAJ) a specialist states it's not possible:

> If the site redirects you to different pages/challenges to login with a password, then I'd suggest checking if you can find any extension or app from Chrome Web Store which can save that password in Chrome. As **this feature isn't available in Chrome**, I'd also suggest submitting feature requests/feedback by using this link.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me atleast on Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Step 1: Type chrome://flags/ in chrome browser and search for 'Google Password Manager UI'. Then enable the Google Password Manager UI feature and restart chrome.

Step 2: Goto Settings --> Advanced --> Passwords. This should open a new Google passsword UI interface which allows you to edit any pre-existing passwords !

I think the password update/save is governed by the websites (I may be wrong here) and sadly web admins assume typing passwords is always secure. I also read that the edit password feature in Chrome settings itself is coming soon, or has it arrived already?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.