# Mass replace a password in Chrome password manager

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management

My workplace uses AD to login for a internal sites (20-30 sites), coupled with a mandatory password change policy every 3 months. Each time I change the password, this invalidates the logins I've saved in Chrome password manager.

In Firefox, I can at least edit the saved password which allows me to more or less do it in a single batch, albeit still manually.

Not so with Chrome - you can delete a password but not edit it. This makes it a pain to change old passwords.

Is there any workaround I could use? Manually editing config files or whatever?

Comment: In chrome, logging in with the new password will ask if you want to change the password. This, of cource still is not a mass replace. Maybe look into a password manager?

Comment: That is what I was hoping to avoid - logging into each site separately and switching the password, but maybe that's the only way.

Comment: check here, it has the answer to your question:
https://superuser.com/a/1370959/955161

Comment: Thank you, would you like to submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is now a function at least on Chrome v`97.0.4692.99` to edit existing passwords. It's still not a mass edit, but it helps a bit more.

[image: Chrome password edit]

Comment: Hi Nikolas. Thank you for the answer. You could add it to https://superuser.com/questions/1341083/how-to-edit-passwords-saved-in-google-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1 as well.